# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: 61141a8345c9ba4338f2af20 }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "LeaveTypes"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, objectid

I was trying to create HRM project using Node and Mongodb (Mongoose) with leave management so for the leave I have created two documents 1. for leavetypes i.e anualLeave, maternityLeave and so on and the other one of taking care of the leave requests taken by the employees.

So here is my schemas and api requests.

```
// leave schema embedded in leaveTypeSchema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Joi = require("joi-browser");
Joi.objectId = require("joi-objectid")(Joi);

const { branchSchema } = require("./branch");
const { employeeSchema } = require("./employee");
const { leaveTypesSchema } = require("./leaveType");

const leaveSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  branch: {
    type: branchSchema,
    required: true,
  },
  employee: {
    type: employeeSchema,
    required: true,
  },
  leaveType: {
    type: [leaveTypesSchema],
    required: true,
  },
  daysRequested: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },

  fromDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  endDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  availableDays: {
    type: Number,
  },
});

const Leave = mongoose.model("leave", leaveSchema);

//validation

function validateLeave(leave) {
  const schema = {
    branchId: Joi.objectId().required(),
    employeeId: Joi.objectId().required(),
    leaveType: Joi.object()
      .keys({
        anualLeave: Joi.object()
          .keys({
            id: Joi.objectId().required(),
          })
          .required(),
      })
      .required(),
    daysRequested: Joi.number().required(),
    fromDate: Joi.date().required(),
    endDate: Joi.date().required(),
  };
  return Joi.validate(leave, schema);
}

module.exports.Leave = Leave;
module.exports.Validate = validateLeave;


//route to post leave requests from employees

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  // validate
  const { error } = Validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
  // check if branch is valid
  let branch = await Branch.findById(req.body.branchId);
  if (!branch) return res.status(400).send("Invalid Branch");
  // check if employee is valid
  let employee = await Employee.findById(req.body.employeeId);
  if (!employee) return res.status(400).send("Invalid employee");
  // check if leaveType is valid
  let leaveType = await LeaveType.findById({
    id: ObjectID(req.body.leaveType.anualLeave.id),
  });
  if (!leaveType) return res.status(400).send("invalid leave Type");
  // post the leave request

  const leave = new Leave({
    branch: {
      _id: branch._id,
      name: branch.name,
    },

    employee: {
  _id: employee._id,
  fullName: employee.fullName,
  phoneNumber: employee.phoneNumber,
  branch: {
    _id: branch._id,
    name: branch.name,
  },
  jobTitle: employee.jobTitle,
  salary: employee.salary,
},
leaveType: [
  {
    anualLeave: {
      id: leaveType.anualLeave.id,
    },
  },
],
daysRequested: req.body.daysRequested,
fromDate: req.body.fromDate,
endDate: req.body.endDate,


});
await leave.save();
res.send(leave);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document doesn't abide by the way you have created your schema.

When you are passing data to model, you have made leavetype nested inside employee

```
const leave = new Leave({
   /**/
    employee: {
      _id: employee._id,
      fullName: employee.fullName,
      phoneNumber: employee.phoneNumber,
      branch: {
        _id: branch._id,
        name: branch.name,
      }, <- here
      leaveType: [
        {
          anualLeave: {
            id: leaveType.anualLeave.id,
          },
        },
      ],
  });
```

whereas in the schema your leaveType is a diff. object property.

```
employee: {
    type: employeeSchema,
    required: true,
  },
  leaveType: {
    type: [leaveTypesSchema],
    required: true,
  },
```

Comment: thanks brother that was clear typo from my side and i corrected it but still am facing the same error

Comment: do update in the question. I will update the question with answer or other will